# My GA Goals Event Setup Not Firing using OnClick Button

Tags: google-analytics

I have setup my button on my page that firing the parameters for ga send event function as following:

```
<a class="aicon-popup btn-subscribeNOW" href="https://www.firstmedia.com/get/global/paket-unlimited-internet-tv-hd" onClick="ga('send', {hitType: 'event',  eventCategory: 'Button',  eventAction: 'Click',  eventLabel: 'RegisterOnline'});"><img class="icn-popup" src="https://dev.firstmedia.com:9443/files/icons/new-landing/icn-subscribeNOW-01.svg" /><b>REGISTER ONLINE</b></a>
```

Here is my goals setup on CMS:

[image]

Anyone can tell me why its not firing?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related may be better suited for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How do you cheсk your goal? And what Google Analytics code do you use on page, ga or gtag?

Comment: here is my analytics script: <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js"></script><script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-****"></script>

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I'm having the same problem